# Justify seconds (integer number) to date format (more than days and months) in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, datetime-format

I would like to know how i can justify big number (million of seconds) to date format **HH:MM:SS** and also **days : months : year** in the same time. Using SQL Query in PostgreSQL 9.4

> Example : 1 000 000 Seconds = 11 days 13 hours 46 minute 40 seconds.

Thank you

Comment: Perhaps ANSI SQL's: `cast(interval'1000000' second as interval day to second)`?

Comment: @jarlh it show me **277: 46 : 40** , so **277** hours and i want to have number of days , months and years from **277**.

Comment: I tried this select `to_char('1000000 second'::interval, 'HH24:mi:ss') ;` and it's the same result , and i can't have more detail if i have more than **24 hours **

Comment: Odd, when I do my cast (as above), I get `11 13:46:40.000000` (not Postgresql though...)

Comment: i'm using PostgreSQL 9.4  and it not show me what i want

Comment: `select to_char(justify_interval('1000000 second')::interval, 'dd "days" hh24 "hours" mi "minute" ss "seconds"');`

Comment: Thank you verry much @Abelisto , it work , however there are a way to have just the not null number , because my **1 000 000 ** it's a dynamic number. Example : **1 000 000 : 0 months , 13 days  ........** or other number 20000000 : 7 months  21 days .......... , i dont want to show **0 months   **

Comment: It is impossible (as I know) for the custom formatting by `to_char` function. Just use `select justify_interval('1000000 second');` instead if you want to quick get the string representation. Also the month number is confusing a bit because it have variable number of days. Use `justify_hours` to get the value in days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
test=> SELECT justify_hours(INTERVAL '1000000 s');
┌──────────────────┐
│  justify_hours   │
├──────────────────┤
│ 11 days 13:46:40 │
└──────────────────┘
(1 row)
```

You can use `justify_interval` instead of `justify_hours` to get months and years, but how many days are there in a month?

Comment: it's works only it's i stop in days , what i want is to have also months and years dynamically (i have a big number) ,  @Abelisto give me this :  
` select to_char(justify_interval('1000000 second')::interval, 'yy "year" mm "months" dd "days" hh24 "hours" mi "minute" ss "seconds"');` but it's not dynamic . Example  : if i have a small number  i have 0 in years 0 in months , etc , and i want just the numbers not the Zeros one

Comment: You can use `justify_interval` for that.  Are you sure that a month is 30 days though?

Comment: Yes i have already did it , however there are a method to change the default label **months** , **years** in justify_interval to french language

Comment: No, but you can use `to_char(interval, text)` to format it as you like.

Comment: i know but if i did it like that  i will lose the dynamic part , i must do all the format , and if i have a small number i will get 0 with labels **years** **month** .......